# What are the reason UTF8 is encoded in PHP json_encode

Tags: php, json

In PHP, by default the json_encode will encode the UTF8 char as hex entities, e.g.

```
$c = json_encode("中"); // return "\u4e2d"
```

Of course you can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to change the behaviours

```
$c = json_encode("中", JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); // return "中"
```

Why this default?

Comment: because that's what the authors of php decided - i'm not sure what kind of answer you expected?

Comment: Feel free to raise an issue / feature request ~ https://bugs.php.net/